# Snakemake: Dynamically change inputs to a rule based on outputs from a previous rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

## Snakemake: Dynamically change inputs to a rule based on outputs from a previous rule

I am trying to build a Snakemake pipeline with the following rules:
At the end of a successful run, I expect the following directory structure:

```
base-path
    |--- dataframe.csv
    |--- success.csv
    |--- result.csv
    |--- images
        |--- image_1
            |--- image.png
            |--- some-measurement.json
        |--- image_2
            |--- image.png
            |--- some-measurement.json
        ...
```

I have a rule download. Given a `df_path`, the script `download.py` downloads images from a server. It downloads the images as shown in the above structure. It also outputs a `success.csv` file which has a list of images that it could successfully download. This rule looks like this:

```
rule download:
    input:
        df_path="base-path/dataframe.csv"
    params:
        x="abcd",
        y=False,
        z="pqrs"
    output:
        "base-path/success.csv"
    threads: 12
    script:
        "scripts/download.py"
```

From the above `success.csv`, I then generate a list of successfully downloaded images which I will need for wildcards in one of the next rules.

```
list_of_wildcards = ["list", "of", "images", "successfully", "downloaded"]
```

My next rule takes all `image.png` and let's say calculates features from them, and save it as a `some-measurement.json` file as shown in the structure described above.

```
rule calculate_something:
    input:
        "base-path/images/{wildcard}/image.png"
    output:
        "base-path/images/{wildcard}/some-measurement.json"
    params:
        x="lmno"
    script:
        "scripts/calculate.sh"
```

In `calculate_something`, I cannot use expand as it just takes one image at a time and performs some calculations. (But if need be, I can change it.)

In my next rule `extract_results`, I take all those `some-measurements.json` files, and concatenate them into a dataframe to save it as `results.csv`

```
rule extract_results:
    input:
        expand("base-path/images/{wildcard}/some.measurement.json", wildcard=list_of_wildcards)
    output:
        "base-path/result.csv"
    params:
        x="some-param"
    threads: 8
    script:
        "scripts/extract.py"
```

And on the top, I have a rule `all` which should perform all these tasks.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "base-path/success.csv"
        "base-path/result.csv"
```

How I want this snakemake workflow to work:

```
- If `result.csv` is not present, it tries to run `extract_results`.
- If `input` to extract_results is not present, it tries to run `calculate_something`.
- and so on.
```

It is skipping `calculate_something` for some reason. I don't understand. My input for `calculate_something` depends on `download`. My input for `extract_results` should depend on `calculate_something`, but I think that is not the case, and hence it is not considering it.

Did someone face a similar issue? Can someone help me out with this? If it is confusing let me know and maybe I can make it more clear.

I tried to use `dynamic`, but I am not able to fully understand the concept. I don't know if that is something that would help me here. Looking forward for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant concept here is [`checkpoint`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) which will trigger re-evaluation of DAG after completion of the relevant rule.